# How to solve "bad operand for binary operator '+' " when used with Generics?

Tags: java, generics

here is my code :

```
class MyExample {

    public static <T,R> R myMethod(T x,R y){
        R z= x+y;// error occurs here
        
        return z;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Integer val = 10;
        String str="Hello World!";
        System.out.println(val+str);// this prints the expected result
        System.out.println(myMethod(10," Hello World!"));
    }

}
```

This code gives error:

> bad operand for binary operator +

When I concat val and str with + it works fine within the main block, But not inside the myMethod.

I don't understand why it happens.

Comment: Java does not allow operator overloading. `+` is only defined on the eight primitives an `String`s.

Comment: You don't even have any restrictions on your generics, so x and y could literally be just `java.lang.Object`. What do you expect the Java compiler to do when you use the plus symbol on `java.lang.Object`?

Comment: Java is not C++, types in generic methods are checked at the declaration site, not at the call site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many people point out already Java does not allow operator overloading so you are bound to use the generic method where `+` is define. `T` and `R` are erased with object meaning they are treated as object because the only common things between `T` and `R` are properties available in object, remember `T` and `R` for the compiler could be any arbitrary types.

The code below is not something i will suggest using, is more of a hack than anything else but it will let you compile, however is prone to many errors in runtime  ***consider yourself warned***

```
class MyExample {

    public static <T ,R > R myMethod(T x, R y){
        return (R) (x.toString() + y.toString());
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Integer val = 10;
        String str="Hello World!";
        System.out.println(val+str);// this prints the expected result
        System.out.println(myMethod(10," Hello World!"));
        System.out.println(myMethod("Hello World!", 10));
    }
}
```

the way that works is by using one of the 8 types where `+` is defined. In the case above we are using String because any object has an string representation with the `toString()` method and then casting the type back to the return type `R`

Now I just to be completely clear the code posted here is just a hack to let you compile please do not use that code for any important code.

So to be honest I would recommend you to rather ask for the behavior you are trying to archive and not about how to fix your current solution since this will only lead to extremely advance code and who knows maybe you need something way simpler.

Comment: Can you explain why `System.out.println(myMethod("Hello World!", 10));` prints the String value seemingly without trying to do the actual cast? Calling `System.out.println(myMethod("Hello World!", 10).getClass());` results in a ClassCastException.

Comment: Disclaimer I have not check the actual output of the java bytecode myselft but I'll try to explain what's going on. Basically since the method is public, static and also a one liner (little code) what some compilers will do as an optimization is to inline the whole method and since the only thing we are doing is to take type R as a String and then calling toString() as you said already there is no cast at all, that why is not failing. Remember I said is more of a hack to let you compile and I do not encourage anyone to use the code above except for experimentation in control environments.

Comment: furthermore if you happen to use any other operation such as save it to a variable or using methods from a class where it cannot be implicitly cast you'll get a wonderful `ClassCastException` as expected, so in other words that method only works when  used as I did any other use will lead to madness (a bunch of error  of course). If  anybody else can confirm thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[Java does not support operator overloading](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c_family_interview.htm). The operator `+` is defined on seven of the eight primitive types (`char`, `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float` and `double`), as well as on `String`.

The types `T` and `R` are unbounded, therefore they are [erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) with `Object`. Since `+` is not defined on `Object`, the compiler generates a compiler error.

`System.out.println(val + str);` works because the right side (`str`) of the expression is a `String`, hence  the compiler tries to convert the left side (`val`) into a `String`. [Every class (at least implicitly) inherits from `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4), therefore every class has an instance method [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) that [is used to convert its instances to `String`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11).